# how to make i in for loop be doubles instead or integers? In other words, how can I make a 4 loop of doubles instead of integers

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, double

This was my original 4 loop

[Shows the for loop that I wrote after the image and the tail of the print as 326.1, 327.1, 328.1, 329.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJcXF.png)

The for loop was

```
a <- 0
for(i in 0:360) {
  a[i] <- (i + 0.01) 
  print (a[i])
}
```

but nothing would help me print it so that I could get 0, 0.01, 0.02, ..., 0.09, 1.00, 1.01...360 instead of 1.01, 2.01, 3.01,...360.1.

I've tried

```
*a <- 0
for(i in 0:360) {
  a[i] <- as.numeric(i + 0.01) 
  print (a[i])
}*
```

but I still got the same vector, 1.01, 2.01, 3.01,...360.1.

I also tried different print functions derivatives of sprintf but those just influenced the amount of significant figures in the output.

Comment: Using 0 as an index in R is not allowed. R is not C.perhaps you should be using seq_along.

Comment: There's a new package on CRAN that allows you to index from zero @IRTFM (https://rdrr.io/cran/index0/ / https://twitter.com/TeaStats/status/1467785202567200768). It feels very, very wrong, but it works: "In R, vector indices start from 1. But everyone knows that you aren't a REAL programmer unless you start counting at 0. Introducing {index0}, my worst #Rstats yet." - David Selby

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

There is now an R package on CRAN that allows you to index a vector starting at zero:

```r
#install.packages("index0")
library(index0)

a <- list()
for (i in as.index0(0:36000)) {
  a[[i + 1]] <- (i / 100) 
}
unlist(a)
#>     [1]   0.00   0.01   0.02   0.03   0.04   0.05   0.06   0.07   0.08   0.09
#>    [11]   0.10   0.11   0.12   0.13   0.14   0.15   0.16   0.17   0.18   0.19
#>    [21]   0.20   0.21   0.22   0.23   0.24   0.25   0.26   0.27   0.28   0.29
#>    [31]   0.30   0.31   0.32   0.33   0.34   0.35   0.36   0.37   0.38   0.39
#>    [41]   0.40   0.41   0.42   0.43   0.44   0.45   0.46   0.47   0.48   0.49
#>    [51]   0.50   0.51   0.52   0.53   0.54   0.55   0.56   0.57   0.58   0.59
#>    [61]   0.60   0.61   0.62   0.63   0.64   0.65   0.66   0.67   0.68   0.69
...
#> [35981] 359.80 359.81 359.82 359.83 359.84 359.85 359.86 359.87 359.88 359.89
#> [35991] 359.90 359.91 359.92 359.93 359.94 359.95 359.96 359.97 359.98 359.99
#> [36001] 360.00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Original (wrong) answer:

I don't think I understand the question properly, but to get the same output as `seq(0, 360, 0.01)`, perhaps something like:

```r
a <- list()
a[1] <- 0
for (i in 1:35900) {
  a[[i + 1]] <- (i / 100) 
}
unlist(a)
#>     [1]   0.00   0.01   0.02   0.03   0.04   0.05   0.06   0.07   0.08   0.09
#>    [11]   0.10   0.11   0.12   0.13   0.14   0.15   0.16   0.17   0.18   0.19
#>    [21]   0.20   0.21   0.22   0.23   0.24   0.25   0.26   0.27   0.28   0.29
#>    [31]   0.30   0.31   0.32   0.33   0.34   0.35   0.36   0.37   0.38   0.39
#>    [41]   0.40   0.41   0.42   0.43   0.44   0.45   0.46   0.47   0.48   0.49
#>    [51]   0.50   0.51   0.52   0.53   0.54   0.55   0.56   0.57   0.58   0.59
#>    [61]   0.60   0.61   0.62   0.63   0.64   0.65   0.66   0.67   0.68   0.69
#>    [71]   0.70   0.71   0.72   0.73   0.74   0.75   0.76   0.77   0.78   0.79
#>    [81]   0.80   0.81   0.82   0.83   0.84   0.85   0.86   0.87   0.88   0.89
#>    [91]   0.90   0.91   0.92   0.93   0.94   0.95   0.96   0.97   0.98   0.99
#>   [101]   1.00   1.01   1.02   1.03   1.04   1.05   1.06   1.07   1.08   1.09
#>   [111]   1.10   1.11   1.12   1.13   1.14   1.15   1.16   1.17   1.18   1.19
#>   [121]   1.20   1.21   1.22   1.23   1.24   1.25   1.26   1.27   1.28   1.29
#>   [131]   1.30   1.31   1.32   1.33   1.34   1.35   1.36   1.37   1.38   1.39
#>   [141]   1.40   1.41   1.42   1.43   1.44   1.45   1.46   1.47   1.48   1.49
#>   [151]   1.50   1.51   1.52   1.53   1.54   1.55   1.56   1.57   1.58   1.59
#>   [161]   1.60   1.61   1.62   1.63   1.64   1.65   1.66   1.67   1.68   1.69
#>   [171]   1.70   1.71   1.72   1.73   1.74   1.75   1.76   1.77   1.78   1.79
#>   [181]   1.80   1.81   1.82   1.83   1.84   1.85   1.86   1.87   1.88   1.89
#>   [191]   1.90   1.91   1.92   1.93   1.94   1.95   1.96   1.97   1.98   1.99
#>   [201]   2.00   2.01   2.02   2.03   2.04   2.05   2.06   2.07   2.08   2.09
#>   [211]   2.10   2.11   2.12   2.13   2.14   2.15   2.16   2.17   2.18   2.19
#>   [221]   2.20   2.21   2.22   2.23   2.24   2.25   2.26   2.27   2.28   2.29
#>   [231]   2.30   2.31   2.32   2.33   2.34   2.35   2.36   2.37   2.38   2.39
#>   [241]   2.40   2.41   2.42   2.43   2.44   2.45   2.46   2.47   2.48   2.49
#>   [251]   2.50   2.51   2.52   2.53   2.54   2.55   2.56   2.57   2.58   2.59
#>   [261]   2.60   2.61   2.62   2.63   2.64   2.65   2.66   2.67   2.68   2.69
#>   [271]   2.70   2.71   2.72   2.73   2.74   2.75   2.76   2.77   2.78   2.79
#>   [281]   2.80   2.81   2.82   2.83   2.84   2.85   2.86   2.87   2.88   2.89
#>   [291]   2.90   2.91   2.92   2.93   2.94   2.95   2.96   2.97   2.98   2.99
#>   [301]   3.00   3.01   3.02   3.03   3.04   3.05   3.06   3.07   3.08   3.09
#>   [311]   3.10   3.11   3.12   3.13   3.14   3.15   3.16   3.17   3.18   3.19
#>   [321]   3.20   3.21   3.22   3.23   3.24   3.25   3.26   3.27   3.28   3.29
#>   [331]   3.30   3.31   3.32   3.33   3.34   3.35   3.36   3.37   3.38   3.39
#>   [341]   3.40   3.41   3.42   3.43   3.44   3.45   3.46   3.47   3.48   3.49
#>   [351]   3.50   3.51   3.52   3.53   3.54   3.55   3.56   3.57   3.58   3.59
#>   [361]   3.60   3.61   3.62   3.63   3.64   3.65   3.66   3.67   3.68   3.69
#>   [371]   3.70   3.71   3.72   3.73   3.74   3.75   3.76   3.77   3.78   3.79
#>   [381]   3.80   3.81   3.82   3.83   3.84   3.85   3.86   3.87   3.88   3.89
#>   [391]   3.90   3.91   3.92   3.93   3.94   3.95   3.96   3.97   3.98   3.99
#>   [401]   4.00   4.01   4.02   4.03   4.04   4.05   4.06   4.07   4.08   4.09
#>   [411]   4.10   4.11   4.12   4.13   4.14   4.15   4.16   4.17   4.18   4.19
#>   [421]   4.20   4.21   4.22   4.23   4.24   4.25   4.26   4.27   4.28   4.29
#>   [431]   4.30   4.31   4.32   4.33   4.34   4.35   4.36   4.37   4.38   4.39
#>   [441]   4.40   4.41   4.42   4.43   4.44   4.45   4.46   4.47   4.48   4.49
#>   [451]   4.50   4.51   4.52   4.53   4.54   4.55   4.56   4.57   4.58   4.59
#>   [461]   4.60   4.61   4.62   4.63   4.64   4.65   4.66   4.67   4.68   4.69
#>   [471]   4.70   4.71   4.72   4.73   4.74   4.75   4.76   4.77   4.78   4.79
#>   [481]   4.80   4.81   4.82   4.83   4.84   4.85   4.86   4.87   4.88   4.89
#>   [491]   4.90   4.91   4.92   4.93   4.94   4.95   4.96   4.97   4.98   4.99
#>   [501]   5.00   5.01   5.02   5.03   5.04   5.05   5.06   5.07   5.08   5.09
#>   [511]   5.10   5.11   5.12   5.13   5.14   5.15   5.16   5.17   5.18   5.19
#>   [521]   5.20   5.21   5.22   5.23   5.24   5.25   5.26   5.27   5.28   5.29
#>   [531]   5.30   5.31   5.32   5.33   5.34   5.35   5.36   5.37   5.38   5.39
#>   [541]   5.40   5.41   5.42   5.43   5.44   5.45   5.46   5.47   5.48   5.49
#>   [551]   5.50   5.51   5.52   5.53   5.54   5.55   5.56   5.57   5.58   5.59
#>   [561]   5.60   5.61   5.62   5.63   5.64   5.65   5.66   5.67   5.68   5.69
#>   [571]   5.70   5.71   5.72   5.73   5.74   5.75   5.76   5.77   5.78   5.79
#>   [581]   5.80   5.81   5.82   5.83   5.84   5.85   5.86   5.87   5.88   5.89
#>   [591]   5.90   5.91   5.92   5.93   5.94   5.95   5.96   5.97   5.98   5.99
#>   [601]   6.00   6.01   6.02   6.03   6.04   6.05   6.06   6.07   6.08   6.09
#>   [611]   6.10   6.11   6.12   6.13   6.14   6.15   6.16   6.17   6.18   6.19
#>   [621]   6.20   6.21   6.22   6.23   6.24   6.25   6.26   6.27   6.28   6.29
#>   [631]   6.30   6.31   6.32   6.33   6.34   6.35   6.36   6.37   6.38   6.39
#>   [641]   6.40   6.41   6.42   6.43   6.44   6.45   6.46   6.47   6.48   6.49
#>   [651]   6.50   6.51   6.52   6.53   6.54   6.55   6.56   6.57   6.58   6.59
#>   [661]   6.60   6.61   6.62   6.63   6.64   6.65   6.66   6.67   6.68   6.69
#>   [671]   6.70   6.71   6.72   6.73   6.74   6.75   6.76   6.77   6.78   6.79
#>   [681]   6.80   6.81   6.82   6.83   6.84   6.85   6.86   6.87   6.88   6.89
#>   [691]   6.90   6.91   6.92   6.93   6.94   6.95   6.96   6.97   6.98   6.99
#>   [701]   7.00   7.01   7.02   7.03   7.04   7.05   7.06   7.07   7.08   7.09
#>   [711]   7.10   7.11   7.12   7.13   7.14   7.15   7.16   7.17   7.18   7.19
#>   [721]   7.20   7.21   7.22   7.23   7.24   7.25   7.26   7.27   7.28   7.29
#>   [731]   7.30   7.31   7.32   7.33   7.34   7.35   7.36   7.37   7.38   7.39
#>   [741]   7.40   7.41   7.42   7.43   7.44   7.45   7.46   7.47   7.48   7.49
#>   [751]   7.50   7.51   7.52   7.53   7.54   7.55   7.56   7.57   7.58   7.59
#>   [761]   7.60   7.61   7.62   7.63   7.64   7.65   7.66   7.67   7.68   7.69
#>   [771]   7.70   7.71   7.72   7.73   7.74   7.75   7.76   7.77   7.78   7.79
#>   [781]   7.80   7.81   7.82   7.83   7.84   7.85   7.86   7.87   7.88   7.89
#>   [791]   7.90   7.91   7.92   7.93   7.94   7.95   7.96   7.97   7.98   7.99
#>   [801]   8.00   8.01   8.02   8.03   8.04   8.05   8.06   8.07   8.08   8.09
#>   [811]   8.10   8.11   8.12   8.13   8.14   8.15   8.16   8.17   8.18   8.19
#>   [821]   8.20   8.21   8.22   8.23   8.24   8.25   8.26   8.27   8.28   8.29
#>   [831]   8.30   8.31   8.32   8.33   8.34   8.35   8.36   8.37   8.38   8.39
#>   [841]   8.40   8.41   8.42   8.43   8.44   8.45   8.46   8.47   8.48   8.49
#>   [851]   8.50   8.51   8.52   8.53   8.54   8.55   8.56   8.57   8.58   8.59
#>   [861]   8.60   8.61   8.62   8.63   8.64   8.65   8.66   8.67   8.68   8.69
#>   [871]   8.70   8.71   8.72   8.73   8.74   8.75   8.76   8.77   8.78   8.79
#>   [881]   8.80   8.81   8.82   8.83   8.84   8.85   8.86   8.87   8.88   8.89
#>   [891]   8.90   8.91   8.92   8.93   8.94   8.95   8.96   8.97   8.98   8.99
#>   [901]   9.00   9.01   9.02   9.03   9.04   9.05   9.06   9.07   9.08   9.09
#>   [911]   9.10   9.11   9.12   9.13   9.14   9.15   9.16   9.17   9.18   9.19
#>   [921]   9.20   9.21   9.22   9.23   9.24   9.25   9.26   9.27   9.28   9.29
#>   [931]   9.30   9.31   9.32   9.33   9.34   9.35   9.36   9.37   9.38   9.39
#>   [941]   9.40   9.41   9.42   9.43   9.44   9.45   9.46   9.47   9.48   9.49
#>   [951]   9.50   9.51   9.52   9.53   9.54   9.55   9.56   9.57   9.58   9.59
#>   [961]   9.60   9.61   9.62   9.63   9.64   9.65   9.66   9.67   9.68   9.69
#>   [971]   9.70   9.71   9.72   9.73   9.74   9.75   9.76   9.77   9.78   9.79
#>   [981]   9.80   9.81   9.82   9.83   9.84   9.85   9.86   9.87   9.88   9.89
#>   [991]   9.90   9.91   9.92   9.93   9.94   9.95   9.96   9.97   9.98   9.99
#>  [1001]  10.00  10.01  10.02  10.03  10.04  10.05  10.06  10.07  10.08  10.09
#>  [1011]  10.10  10.11  10.12  10.13  10.14  10.15  10.16  10.17  10.18  10.19
#>  [1021]  10.20  10.21  10.22  10.23  10.24  10.25  10.26  10.27  10.28  10.29
#>  [1031]  10.30  10.31  10.32  10.33  10.34  10.35  10.36  10.37  10.38  10.39
#>  [1041]  10.40  10.41  10.42  10.43  10.44  10.45  10.46  10.47  10.48  10.49
#>  [1051]  10.50  10.51  10.52  10.53  10.54  10.55  10.56  10.57  10.58  10.59
#>  [1061]  10.60  10.61  10.62  10.63  10.64  10.65  10.66  10.67  10.68  10.69
#>  [1071]  10.70  10.71  10.72  10.73  10.74  10.75  10.76  10.77  10.78  10.79
#>  [1081]  10.80  10.81  10.82  10.83  10.84  10.85  10.86  10.87  10.88  10.89
#>  [1091]  10.90  10.91  10.92  10.93  10.94  10.95  10.96  10.97  10.98  10.99
#>  [1101]  11.00  11.01  11.02  11.03  11.04  11.05  11.06  11.07  11.08  11.09
#>  [1111]  11.10  11.11  11.12  11.13  11.14  11.15  11.16  11.17  11.18  11.19
#>  [1121]  11.20  11.21  11.22  11.23  11.24  11.25  11.26  11.27  11.28  11.29
#>  [1131]  11.30  11.31  11.32  11.33  11.34  11.35  11.36  11.37  11.38  11.39
#>  [1141]  11.40  11.41  11.42  11.43  11.44  11.45  11.46  11.47  11.48  11.49
#>  [1151]  11.50  11.51  11.52  11.53  11.54  11.55  11.56  11.57  11.58  11.59
#>  [1161]  11.60  11.61  11.62  11.63  11.64  11.65  11.66  11.67  11.68  11.69
#>  [1171]  11.70  11.71  11.72  11.73  11.74  11.75  11.76  11.77  11.78  11.79
#>  [1181]  11.80  11.81  11.82  11.83  11.84  11.85  11.86  11.87  11.88  11.89
#>  [1191]  11.90  11.91  11.92  11.93  11.94  11.95  11.96  11.97  11.98  11.99
#>  [1201]  12.00  12.01  12.02  12.03  12.04  12.05  12.06  12.07  12.08  12.09
#>  [1211]  12.10  12.11  12.12  12.13  12.14  12.15  12.16  12.17  12.18  12.19
#>  [1221]  12.20  12.21  12.22  12.23  12.24  12.25  12.26  12.27  12.28  12.29
#>  [1231]  12.30  12.31  12.32  12.33  12.34  12.35  12.36  12.37  12.38  12.39
#>  [1241]  12.40  12.41  12.42  12.43  12.44  12.45  12.46  12.47  12.48  12.49
#>  [1251]  12.50  12.51  12.52  12.53  12.54  12.55  12.56  12.57  12.58  12.59
#>  [1261]  12.60  12.61  12.62  12.63  12.64  12.65  12.66  12.67  12.68  12.69
#>  [1271]  12.70  12.71  12.72  12.73  12.74  12.75  12.76  12.77  12.78  12.79
#>  [1281]  12.80  12.81  12.82  12.83  12.84  12.85  12.86  12.87  12.88  12.89
#>  [1291]  12.90  12.91  12.92  12.93  12.94  12.95  12.96  12.97  12.98  12.99
#>  [1301]  13.00  13.01  13.02  13.03  13.04  13.05  13.06  13.07  13.08  13.09
#>  [1311]  13.10  13.11  13.12  13.13  13.14  13.15  13.16  13.17  13.18  13.19
#>  [1321]  13.20  13.21  13.22  13.23  13.24  13.25  13.26  13.27  13.28  13.29
#>  [1331]  13.30  13.31  13.32  13.33  13.34  13.35  13.36  13.37  13.38  13.39
#>  [1341]  13.40  13.41  13.42  13.43  13.44  13.45  13.46  13.47  13.48  13.49
#>  [1351]  13.50  13.51  13.52  13.53  13.54  13.55  13.56  13.57  13.58  13.59
#>  [1361]  13.60  13.61  13.62  13.63  13.64  13.65  13.66  13.67  13.68  13.69
#>  [1371]  13.70  13.71  13.72  13.73  13.74  13.75  13.76  13.77  13.78  13.79
#>  [1381]  13.80  13.81  13.82  13.83  13.84  13.85  13.86  13.87  13.88  13.89
#>  [1391]  13.90  13.91  13.92  13.93  13.94  13.95  13.96  13.97  13.98  13.99
#>  [1401]  14.00  14.01  14.02  14.03  14.04  14.05  14.06  14.07  14.08  14.09
#>  [1411]  14.10  14.11  14.12  14.13  14.14  14.15  14.16  14.17  14.18  14.19
#>  [1421]  14.20  14.21  14.22  14.23  14.24  14.25  14.26  14.27  14.28  14.29
#>  [1431]  14.30  14.31  14.32  14.33  14.34  14.35  14.36  14.37  14.38  14.39
#>  [1441]  14.40  14.41  14.42  14.43  14.44  14.45  14.46  14.47  14.48  14.49
#>  [1451]  14.50  14.51  14.52  14.53  14.54  14.55  14.56  14.57  14.58  14.59
#>  [1461]  14.60  14.61  14.62  14.63  14.64  14.65  14.66  14.67  14.68  14.69
#>  [1471]  14.70  14.71  14.72  14.73  14.74  14.75  14.76  14.77  14.78  14.79
#>  [1481]  14.80  14.81  14.82  14.83  14.84  14.85  14.86  14.87  14.88  14.89
#>  [1491]  14.90  14.91  14.92  14.93  14.94  14.95  14.96  14.97  14.98  14.99
#>  [1501]  15.00  15.01  15.02  15.03  15.04  15.05  15.06  15.07  15.08  15.09
#>  [1511]  15.10  15.11  15.12  15.13  15.14  15.15  15.16  15.17  15.18  15.19
#>  [1521]  15.20  15.21  15.22  15.23  15.24  15.25  15.26  15.27  15.28  15.29
#>  [1531]  15.30  15.31  15.32  15.33  15.34  15.35  15.36  15.37  15.38  15.39
#>  [1541]  15.40  15.41  15.42  15.43  15.44  15.45  15.46  15.47  15.48  15.49
#>  [1551]  15.50  15.51  15.52  15.53  15.54  15.55  15.56  15.57  15.58  15.59
#>  [1561]  15.60  15.61  15.62  15.63  15.64  15.65  15.66  15.67  15.68  15.69
#>  [1571]  15.70  15.71  15.72  15.73  15.74  15.75  15.76  15.77  15.78  15.79
#>  [1581]  15.80  15.81  15.82  15.83  15.84  15.85  15.86  15.87  15.88  15.89
#>  [1591]  15.90  15.91  15.92  15.93  15.94  15.95  15.96  15.97  15.98  15.99
#>  [1601]  16.00  16.01  16.02  16.03  16.04  16.05  16.06  16.07  16.08  16.09
#>  [1611]  16.10  16.11  16.12  16.13  16.14  16.15  16.16  16.17  16.18  16.19
#>  [1621]  16.20  16.21  16.22  16.23  16.24  16.25  16.26  16.27  16.28  16.29
#>  [1631]  16.30  16.31  16.32  16.33  16.34  16.35  16.36  16.37  16.38  16.39
#>  [1641]  16.40  16.41  16.42  16.43  16.44  16.45  16.46  16.47  16.48  16.49
#>  [1651]  16.50  16.51  16.52  16.53  16.54  16.55  16.56  16.57  16.58  16.59
#>  [1661]  16.60  16.61  16.62  16.63  16.64  16.65  16.66  16.67  16.68  16.69
#>  [1671]  16.70  16.71  16.72  16.73  16.74  16.75  16.76  16.77  16.78  16.79
#>  [1681]  16.80  16.81  16.82  16.83  16.84  16.85  16.86  16.87  16.88  16.89
#>  [1691]  16.90  16.91  16.92  16.93  16.94  16.95  16.96  16.97  16.98  16.99
#>  [1701]  17.00  17.01  17.02  17.03  17.04  17.05  17.06  17.07  17.08  17.09
#>  [1711]  17.10  17.11  17.12  17.13  17.14  17.15  17.16  17.17  17.18  17.19
#>  [1721]  17.20  17.21  17.22  17.23  17.24  17.25  17.26  17.27  17.28  17.29
#>  [1731]  17.30  17.31  17.32  17.33  17.34  17.35  17.36  17.37  17.38  17.39
#>  [1741]  17.40  17.41  17.42  17.43  17.44  17.45  17.46  17.47  17.48  17.49
#>  [1751]  17.50  17.51  17.52  17.53  17.54  17.55  17.56  17.57  17.58  17.59
#>  [1761]  17.60  17.61  17.62  17.63  17.64  17.65  17.66  17.67  17.68  17.69
#>  [1771]  17.70  17.71  17.72  17.73  17.74  17.75  17.76  17.77  17.78  17.79
#>  [1781]  17.80  17.81  17.82  17.83  17.84  17.85  17.86  17.87  17.88  17.89
#>  [1791]  17.90  17.91  17.92  17.93  17.94  17.95  17.96  17.97  17.98  17.99
#>  [1801]  18.00  18.01  18.02  18.03  18.04  18.05  18.06  18.07  18.08  18.09
#>  [1811]  18.10  18.11  18.12  18.13  18.14  18.15  18.16  18.17  18.18  18.19
#>  [1821]  18.20  18.21  18.22  18.23  18.24  18.25  18.26  18.27  18.28  18.29
#>  [1831]  18.30  18.31  18.32  18.33  18.34  18.35  18.36  18.37  18.38  18.39
#>  [1841]  18.40  18.41  18.42  18.43  18.44  18.45  18.46  18.47  18.48  18.49
#>  [1851]  18.50  18.51  18.52  18.53  18.54  18.55  18.56  18.57  18.58  18.59
#>  [1861]  18.60  18.61  18.62  18.63  18.64  18.65  18.66  18.67  18.68  18.69
#>  [1871]  18.70  18.71  18.72  18.73  18.74  18.75  18.76  18.77  18.78  18.79
#>  [1881]  18.80  18.81  18.82  18.83  18.84  18.85  18.86  18.87  18.88  18.89
#>  [1891]  18.90  18.91  18.92  18.93  18.94  18.95  18.96  18.97  18.98  18.99
#>  [1901]  19.00  19.01  19.02  19.03  19.04  19.05  19.06  19.07  19.08  19.09
#>  [1911]  19.10  19.11  19.12  19.13  19.14  19.15  19.16  19.17  19.18  19.19
#>  [1921]  19.20  19.21  19.22  19.23  19.24  19.25  19.26  19.27  19.28  19.29
#>  [1931]  19.30  19.31  19.32  19.33  19.34  19.35  19.36  19.37  19.38  19.39
#>  [1941]  19.40  19.41  19.42  19.43  19.44  19.45  19.46  19.47  19.48  19.49
#>  [1951]  19.50  19.51  19.52  19.53  19.54  19.55  19.56  19.57  19.58  19.59
#>  [1961]  19.60  19.61  19.62  19.63  19.64  19.65  19.66  19.67  19.68  19.69
#>  [1971]  19.70  19.71  19.72  19.73  19.74  19.75  19.76  19.77  19.78  19.79
#>  [1981]  19.80  19.81  19.82  19.83  19.84  19.85  19.86  19.87  19.88  19.89
#>  [1991]  19.90  19.91  19.92  19.93  19.94  19.95  19.96  19.97  19.98  19.99
#>  [2001]  20.00  20.01  20.02  20.03  20.04  20.05  20.06  20.07  20.08  20.09
#>  [2011]  20.10  20.11  20.12  20.13  20.14  20.15  20.16  20.17  20.18  20.19
#>  [2021]  20.20  20.21  20.22  20.23  20.24  20.25  20.26  20.27  20.28  20.29
#>  [2031]  20.30  20.31  20.32  20.33  20.34  20.35  20.36  20.37  20.38  20.39
#>  [2041]  20.40  20.41  20.42  20.43  20.44  20.45  20.46  20.47  20.48  20.49
#>  [2051]  20.50  20.51  20.52  20.53  20.54  20.55  20.56  20.57  20.58  20.59
#>  [2061]  20.60  20.61  20.62  20.63  20.64  20.65  20.66  20.67  20.68  20.69
#>  [2071]  20.70  20.71  20.72  20.73  20.74  20.75  20.76  20.77  20.78  20.79
#>  [2081]  20.80  20.81  20.82  20.83  20.84  20.85  20.86  20.87  20.88  20.89
#>  [2091]  20.90  20.91  20.92  20.93  20.94  20.95  20.96  20.97  20.98  20.99
#>  [2101]  21.00  21.01  21.02  21.03  21.04  21.05  21.06  21.07  21.08  21.09
#>  [2111]  21.10  21.11  21.12  21.13  21.14  21.15  21.16  21.17  21.18  21.19
#>  [2121]  21.20  21.21  21.22  21.23  21.24  21.25  21.26  21.27  21.28  21.29
#>  [2131]  21.30  21.31  21.32  21.33  21.34  21.35  21.36  21.37  21.38  21.39
#>  [2141]  21.40  21.41  21.42  21.43  21.44  21.45  21.46  21.47  21.48  21.49
#>  [2151]  21.50  21.51  21.52  21.53  21.54  21.55  21.56  21.57  21.58  21.59
#>  [2161]  21.60  21.61  21.62  21.63  21.64  21.65  21.66  21.67  21.68  21.69
#>  [2171]  21.70  21.71  21.72  21.73  21.74  21.75  21.76  21.77  21.78  21.79
#>  [2181]  21.80  21.81  21.82  21.83  21.84  21.85  21.86  21.87  21.88  21.89
#>  [2191]  21.90  21.91  21.92  21.93  21.94  21.95  21.96  21.97  21.98  21.99
#>  [2201]  22.00  22.01  22.02  22.03  22.04  22.05  22.06  22.07  22.08  22.09
#>  [2211]  22.10  22.11  22.12  22.13  22.14  22.15  22.16  22.17  22.18  22.19
#>  [2221]  22.20  22.21  22.22  22.23  22.24  22.25  22.26  22.27  22.28  22.29
#>  [2231]  22.30  22.31  22.32  22.33  22.34  22.35  22.36  22.37  22.38  22.39
#>  [2241]  22.40  22.41  22.42  22.43  22.44  22.45  22.46  22.47  22.48  22.49
#>  [2251]  22.50  22.51  22.52  22.53  22.54  22.55  22.56  22.57  22.58  22.59
#>  [2261]  22.60  22.61  22.62  22.63  22.64  22.65  22.66  22.67  22.68  22.69
#>  [2271]  22.70  22.71  22.72  22.73  22.74  22.75  22.76  22.77  22.78  22.79
#>  [2281]  22.80  22.81  22.82  22.83  22.84  22.85  22.86  22.87  22.88  22.89
#>  [2291]  22.90  22.91  22.92  22.93  22.94  22.95  22.96  22.97  22.98  22.99
#>  [2301]  23.00  23.01  23.02  23.03  23.04  23.05  23.06  23.07  23.08  23.09
#>  [2311]  23.10  23.11  23.12  23.13  23.14  23.15  23.16  23.17  23.18  23.19
#>  [2321]  23.20  23.21  23.22  23.23  23.24  23.25  23.26  23.27  23.28  23.29
#>  [2331]  23.30  23.31  23.32  23.33  23.34  23.35  23.36  23.37  23.38  23.39
#>  [2341]  23.40  23.41  23.42  23.43  23.44  23.45  23.46  23.47  23.48  23.49
#>  [2351]  23.50  23.51  23.52  23.53  23.54  23.55  23.56  23.57  23.58  23.59
#>  [2361]  23.60  23.61  23.62  23.63  23.64  23.65  23.66  23.67  23.68  23.69
#>  [2371]  23.70  23.71  23.72  23.73  23.74  23.75  23.76  23.77  23.78  23.79
#>  [2381]  23.80  23.81  23.82  23.83  23.84  23.85  23.86  23.87  23.88  23.89
#>  [2391]  23.90  23.91  23.92  23.93  23.94  23.95  23.96  23.97  23.98  23.99
#>  [2401]  24.00  24.01  24.02  24.03  24.04  24.05  24.06  24.07  24.08  24.09
#>  [2411]  24.10  24.11  24.12  24.13  24.14  24.15  24.16  24.17  24.18  24.19
#>  [2421]  24.20  24.21  24.22  24.23  24.24  24.25  24.26  24.27  24.28  24.29
#>  [2431]  24.30  24.31  24.32  24.33  24.34  24.35  24.36  24.37  24.38  24.39
#>  [2441]  24.40  24.41  24.42  24.43  24.44  24.45  24.46  24.47  24.48  24.49
#>  [2451]  24.50  24.51  24.52  24.53  24.54  24.55  24.56  24.57  24.58  24.59
#>  [2461]  24.60  24.61  24.62  24.63  24.64  24.65  24.66  24.67  24.68  24.69
#>  [2471]  24.70  24.71  24.72  24.73  24.74  24.75  24.76  24.77  24.78  24.79
#>  [2481]  24.80  24.81  24.82  24.83  24.84  24.85  24.86  24.87  24.88  24.89
#>  [2491]  24.90  24.91  24.92  24.93  24.94  24.95  24.96  24.97  24.98  24.99
#>  [2501]  25.00  25.01  25.02  25.03  25.04  25.05  25.06  25.07  25.08  25.09
#>  [2511]  25.10  25.11  25.12  25.13  25.14  25.15  25.16  25.17  25.18  25.19
#>  [2521]  25.20  25.21  25.22  25.23  25.24  25.25  25.26  25.27  25.28  25.29
#>  [2531]  25.30  25.31  25.32  25.33  25.34  25.35  25.36  25.37  25.38  25.39
#>  [2541]  25.40  25.41  25.42  25.43  25.44  25.45  25.46  25.47  25.48  25.49
#>  [2551]  25.50  25.51  25.52  25.53  25.54  25.55  25.56  25.57  25.58  25.59
#>  [2561]  25.60  25.61  25.62  25.63  25.64  25.65  25.66  25.67  25.68  25.69
#>  [2571]  25.70  25.71  25.72  25.73  25.74  25.75  25.76  25.77  25.78  25.79
#>  [2581]  25.80  25.81  25.82  25.83  25.84  25.85  25.86  25.87  25.88  25.89
#>  [2591]  25.90  25.91  25.92  25.93  25.94  25.95  25.96  25.97  25.98  25.99
#>  [2601]  26.00  26.01  26.02  26.03  26.04  26.05  26.06  26.07  26.08  26.09
#>  [2611]  26.10  26.11  26.12  26.13  26.14  26.15  26.16  26.17  26.18  26.19
#>  [2621]  26.20  26.21  26.22  26.23  26.24  26.25  26.26  26.27  26.28  26.29
#>  [2631]  26.30  26.31  26.32  26.33  26.34  26.35  26.36  26.37  26.38  26.39
#>  [2641]  26.40  26.41  26.42  26.43  26.44  26.45  26.46  26.47  26.48  26.49
#>  [2651]  26.50  26.51  26.52  26.53  26.54  26.55  26.56  26.57  26.58  26.59
#>  [2661]  26.60  26.61  26.62  26.63  26.64  26.65  26.66  26.67  26.68  26.69
#>  [2671]  26.70  26.71  26.72  26.73  26.74  26.75  26.76  26.77  26.78  26.79
#>  [2681]  26.80  26.81  26.82  26.83  26.84  26.85  26.86  26.87  26.88  26.89
#>  [2691]  26.90  26.91  26.92  26.93  26.94  26.95  26.96  26.97  26.98  26.99
#>  [2701]  27.00  27.01  27.02  27.03  27.04  27.05  27.06  27.07  27.08  27.09
#>  [2711]  27.10  27.11  27.12  27.13  27.14  27.15  27.16  27.17  27.18  27.19
#>  [2721]  27.20  27.21  27.22  27.23  27.24  27.25  27.26  27.27  27.28  27.29
#>  [2731]  27.30  27.31  27.32  27.33  27.34  27.35  27.36  27.37  27.38  27.39
#>  [2741]  27.40  27.41  27.42  27.43  27.44  27.45  27.46  27.47  27.48  27.49
#>  [2751]  27.50  27.51  27.52  27.53  27.54  27.55  27.56  27.57  27.58  27.59
...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Is that what you're trying to do? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Hi Jared actually this isnt

Comment: I tried your command and didn't get enough values

Comment: I am not sure if I just have a printing issue. Why would you put  [[ i + 1 ]] in your code to get your results that adds 0.01 to each value like I want.

Comment: a <- list()
a[1] <- 0
for (i in 1:3.59) {
  a[[i + 1.01]] <- (i / 100) 
  print(a[[i + 1]])
}

Comment: then I would get 0.01, 0.02, 0.03

Comment: a <- list()
a[1] <- 0
for (i in 1:3.6) {
  a[[i + 1]] <- (i / 100)
  print(a[[i + 1]])
}  and with this I would also get just 0.01, 0.02, 0.3

Comment: nevermine i got it. I just needed to change it  i in 0:360

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help; I didn't really understand what you wanted to do. Glad you worked it out.